# I can't call on RoutedEventArgs's nested data without "does not contain a definition" error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have code that creates a ListBoxItem for each of the first 100 values in query, and holds data such as ID, Address, etc. I also have an event so that when the ListBoxItem is created, it displays the address in a textbox so that a search can be done with the address(not included in code)

```
foreach (var item in query)
   {
   if (i < 100)
   {
      var listboxitem = new ListBoxItem();
      listboxitem.Content = item.Address_Full;
      listboxitem.Selected += Address_Clicked;
      listboxitem.Tag = new AddressInfo(item.ID, item.Nickname, item.Address_Full, item.Units, 
      item.RegionID, item.Notes, item.RecordSource);
      AddressListBox.Items.Add(listboxitem);
   }
      else
          break;
      i++;
}
```

```
private void Address_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = e.OriginalSource.ToString().Replace("System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: ", "");
            GeocodeAddressTbx.Text = source;
        }
```

So when I put a breakpoint in the code, I can see that e has "Original Source" and under it it has the "Tag" that I set earlier in the first code box.

[image]

I know the information's there, but I do not know how to call on it, as e.OriginalSource.Tag would just give me a "does not contain a definition for 'Tag'" error. I think this is a kind of a general problem not that specific to my case so I hope that's enough information. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You need to cast OriginalSource to the type with those properties.  The object you are accessing is of type `object`, which only has the methods shown in the bottom image.

Answer (score 1):

use `sender` parameter. it should be ListBoxItem, because event handler is attached to listBoxItem event

```
private void Address_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GeocodeAddressTbx.Text = ((ListBoxItem)sender).Content.ToString();
}
```

---

but you can also use the power of bindings and do this:

1 - use ItemsSource instead of loop:

```
AddressListBox.ItemsSource = query.Take(100).ToList();
AddressListBox.DisplayMemberPath = nameof(AddressInfo.Address_Full);
/*foreach (var item in query)
   {
   if (i < 100)
   {
      var listboxitem = new ListBoxItem();
      listboxitem.Content = item.Address_Full;
      listboxitem.Selected += Address_Clicked;
      listboxitem.Tag = new AddressInfo(item.ID, item.Nickname, item.Address_Full, item.Units, 
      item.RegionID, item.Notes, item.RecordSource);
      AddressListBox.Items.Add(listboxitem);
   }
      else
          break;
      i++;
}*/
```

2 - bind TextBox to selected item:

```
<TextBox Name="GeocodeAddressTbx" 
         Text="{Binding ElementName=AddressListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Address_Full}"/>
```